# Secure mobile SD card with a PIN/code

Tags: android, mobile, windows-phone

Is there a way to set a PIN on your SD card so that in case mobile is lost or stolen, the contents of SD card like photos, docs etc. cannot be seen by anyone else? I am asking for SIM card PIN protection like functionality. On mobiles you can set a PIN lock on your SIM so that if you restart your mobile or use that SIM on another phone you have to provide that PIN to use the SIM again. But these days using SD card as secondary memory is widespread and lots of personal data is stored on them so it will be helpful if there is PIN protect like facility. So please tell me if its possible on any mobile or any app. The app should make SD card unusable without formatting everything on it.

I am asking for an app or inbuilt functionality on both Android and Windows mobile phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into the SD card - its basically dumb storage.

What you can do is encrypt files on the device - either individually or the entire filesystem. Modern android supports this natively - under "Security" or "Lock screen & security" etc (depending on manufacturer) look for the encryption section. This works well when the SD card is used as an extension of the built in storage. If you wish to use the card to transfer data you will likely struggle - [this answer suggests it isn't possible with standard tools](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/155142).

As far as I am aware Windows phone does not offer a similar feature. I'm sure there would be some applications which supported encrypting files on the filesystem - but this wouldn't play well with other apps accessing them.